# Reading files sequentially from a list of files, make an array and slicing data from the array within for loop in python

Tags: python, arrays, math, pandas-groupby, slice

I've several BIG data `*.npy` files. As the file size is BIG so I want to read 2 files at a time, append them to make an array and then I do slicing the array of desired size. For simplicity, consider every `*.npy` file contains `n` no. of rows (i.e. `n=50000000` rows) while I want to slice `m` no. of rows (`m=43200000` rows) and save the sliced array for further work. Due to memory constraints, I can read only 2 files at a time.

I can do it manually every time to create *.npy file which is not efficient. Can anybody help me to make this task efficiently by using `for/while`? I've shown whatever I've done

```
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
import time

path = '/work/ABC_pack/res_array_13*.npy' # 100 files
t0 = time.time()
# Files in the directory
filenames = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob(path)]
# Sorting files numerically
filelist = sorted(filenames, key=lambda x:float(re.findall("(\d+)",x)[0]))
print(filelist);
no_files = len(filelist)
print('Total No. of Files : ', no_files)

# Consider a specific case, n=13; I choose n=13 on a random basis
n = 13 # No. of files, n=1,2,3,.....13....100 

#*************************************
f1 = filelist[n]
print('file one',f1 )
arr1 = np.load(f1)
print('Shape of Array 1', arr1.shape)

#****************************
f2 = filelist[n+1]
print('file one',f2 )
arr2 = np.load(f2)
print('Shape of Array 2', arr2.shape)

# Stacking the two arrays vertically
my_arr = np.vstack((arr1, arr2))
del arr1 # Delete the array 1
del arr2 # Delete the array 2
print ("Shape of  vertically stacked array:\n ", my_arr.shape)

slice_data  = 43200000 # No. of rows to be sliced to create new .npy file
file_dat = 50000000    # No. of rows in a .npy file

#nxt_day_dat = my_arr[0:slice_data, :] # First file
#nxt_day_dat = my_arr[slice_data:slice_data*2, :] # Second file
nxt_day_dat = my_arr[((n+3)*slice_data-file_dat*n):((n+4)*slice_data-file_dat*n), :] 
del my_arr
# File saving
np.save('test{0}.npy'.format(n+3), nxt_day_dat)
t2 = time.time()-t0
print('Time spent= {} seconds'.format(t2))
```

As I want to use `for loop` so I've tried with the following script but this script don't give me desired output. I can locate the problem but no idea how to tackle this problem. Can anybody help me?

```
day_dat = 86400 * 500
file_dat = 50000000

for n in range(no_files):
    f1 = filelist[n]
    print('file one', f1)
    arr1 = np.load(f1)
    print('Shape of Array 1', arr1.shape)

    # ****************************
    f2 = filelist[n + 1]
    print('file one', f2)
    arr2 = np.load(f2)
    print('Shape of Array 2', arr2.shape)

    # Stacking the two arrays vertically
    my_arr = np.vstack((arr1, arr2))
    del arr1
    del arr2

    print("Shape of  vertically stacked array:\n ", my_arr.shape)

    if n==0:
        slice_dat = my_arr[day_dat*n:day_dat*(n+1), :]  # for the 1st file
    elif n==1:
        slice_dat = my_arr[day_dat*n:day_dat * (n+1), :]  # for the 2nd file
    else:
# Problems with slicing when the value of loop index, n=7,14, 30.....
        slice_dat = my_arr[((n + 1) * day_dat - file_dat * n):((n + 2) * day_dat - file_dat * n), :]
    del my_arr
    # File saving
    np.save('npy_file{0}.npy'.format(n + 1), slice_dat)

t2 = time.time()-t0
print('Time spent= {} seconds'.format(t2))
```

Comment: If `filelist` is 13 elements long, how do you read `filelist[13]` and `filelist[14]` ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, thanks for comment.  `filelist` is long enough (let there are 50 files) but I choose to create a specific `*.npy` file of 432 rows. I've  created the `*.npy` file once at a time, looking for an efficient approach.